# Проблема с attr Android на minSDK

Tags: android, kotlin, android-sdk

на Android 8.0 работает отлично.

на Android 4.1 падает

```
02-06 15:20:17.373 4246-4246/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49: Error inflating class TextView
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.ui.album_list.AlbumListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AlbumListAdapter.kt:22)
        at ru.ddstudio.simpleitunesapp.ui.album_list.AlbumListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(AlbumListAdapter.kt:14)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7078)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6235)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.layoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:1183)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayoutChild(CoordinatorLayout.java:870)
        at androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout.onLayout(CoordinatorLayout.java:889)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1649)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1507)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1420)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:448)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:13754)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4364)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1868)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1689)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4214)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreogr
```

Посмотрев на TextView я начал экспериментировать, чтобы узнать ошибку

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_price"
        style="@style/TextView.Counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_counter"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minWidth="@dimen/counter_size"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_collection_name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tv_collection_name"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/tv_collection_name"
        tools:text="13,33 USD" />
```

было определено, что падает из-за `android:background="@drawable/bg_counter"`

bg_counter состоит из

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
            <solid android:color="?attr/colorCounter"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

Цвет я устанавливаю с помощью темы:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorItemView">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorTitle">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorText">@color/color_gray_dark</item>
        <item name="colorCounter">@color/color_indicator</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Сначала я подумал, что это из-за цвета, но поменяв его, ошибка не исчезла.
Затем я подумал, что из-за темы, поэтому создал отдельный themes.xml (v21) и поменял родителя

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <item name="colorItemView">@android:color/white</item>
        <item name="colorTitle">@color/color_primary</item>
        <item name="colorText">@color/color_gray_dark</item>
        <item name="colorCounter">@color/color_indicator</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

Но ошибка также не исчезла.

Затем я вместо attr вставил цвет напрямую

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <corners android:radius="10dp"/>
<!--            <solid android:color="?attr/colorCounter"/>-->
            <solid android:color="@color/color_indicator"/>
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

И у меня все заработало. В чем была ошибка?

Comment: Задавание цвета через атрибуты, вместо конкретного цвета, вроде как, только с 21 API поддерживается. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27986204/cant-convert-to-color-type-0x2-error-when-inflating-layout-in-fragment-but-onl/34279007#34279007

Comment: Вариант костыля для API<21: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13471695

Answer (score 2):

Используйте AppCompatTextView. Он поддерживает на старых API то, что поддерживается начиная с API 21. У меня это решило проблему.